# Unable to delete post from a user on backend sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, controller, sequelize.js

I'm trying to learn sequelize v6. I've already created a database with 3 tables (users, posts, and evaluations). In my controller folder, I have three files (UserController.js, PostController.js, and EvaluationController.js) where I make my default controls like create the users, create the posts, and create the Evaluations, what is working properly, but now I'm trying to create a delete function inside my PostController, but I have no idea why it is not working.

Here is my UserConroller file:

```
const User = require('../models/User');
const Post = require('../models/Post');

module.exports = {
  async index (req, res) {
    const { user_id } = req.params;

    const user = await User.findByPk(user_id, {
      include: { association: 'posts' }
    });

    return res.json(user.posts);
  },

  async store(req, res) {
    const { user_id } = req.params;
    const { description, image_url, latitude, longitude } = req.body;

    const user = await User.findByPk(user_id);

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'User not found' });
    }

    const post = await Post.create({ description, image_url, latitude, longitude, user_id });

    return res.json(post);
  },

  async delete(req, res) {
    const { user_id } = req.params;
    const { name } = req.body;

    const user = await User.findByPk(user_id);

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "User not found" });
    }

    const post = await Post.findOne({
      where: { name }
    });

    await user.removeUser(post);

    return res.json();
  },

  async delete(req, res) {
    const { user_id } = req.params;
    const { image_url } = req.body;

    const  user = await Post.findByPk(user_id);

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Post not found' });
    }

    const post = await Post.findOne({
      where: { image_url }
    });

    await user.removePost(post);

    return res.json();
  }
};
```

In the routes.js file I have these routes for the posts:

```
routes.get('/users/:user_id/post', PostController.index);
routes.post('/users/:user_id/post', PostController.store);
routes.delete('/users/:user_id/post', PostController.delete);
```

In my models' folder I have Post.js that's where I use sequelize to control my backend:

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

class Post extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init({
      description: DataTypes.STRING,
      image_url: DataTypes.STRING,
      latitude: DataTypes.STRING,
      longitude: DataTypes.STRING,
    }, {
      sequelize
    })
  }

  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'user_id', as: 'owner' });
    this.hasMany(models.Evaluation, { foreignKey: 'post_id', as: 'evaluations' });
  }
}

module.exports = Post;
```

I've already created 3 users inside my users table with the columns: id, user_id description, image_url latitude, longitude, created_at, updated_at

When I try to delete the post I have created with the id 1, user_id: 3, description: Any description because I want to, image_url: https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.E4gCagrjAkQ5td5qjSc3rwHaE7%26pid%3DApi&f=1, latitude: -10.962526333931583, longitude: -37.103513513954375, created_at: 2021-08-13 23:56:58, and updated_at: 2021-08-13 23:56:58, as I have requested for the image_url to be sent as param I send the same image_url that is inside the database column, but my post is not being deleted, I see no error message instead of the JSON `{ "error": "Post not found" }` and in the console it shows:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `description`, `image_url`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `created_at` AS `createdAt`, `updated_at` AS `updatedAt`, `user_id` FROM `posts` AS `Post` WHERE `Post`.`id` = '3';
```

What am I missing there to have my post deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im pretty sure you need to change the way you are deleting the posts, currently you're doing user.removePost(post), which is not a function on the hasOne/belongsTo association (If you're using a hasMany/belongsTo association then you shouldnt have any issues).

Also you should rename your functions to be a little more descriptive, since you have 2 delete functions doing different things

You need to run a Post.destroy() on the post itself, it will my befault delete the assocation on the user. (Since user.removePost(post) only removes it from the user and doesnt delete it from the database)

```
module.exports = {
    async deletePostByName (req, res) {
        try {
            const postName = req.query.name // Delete http requests usually use a query and not a body

            await Post.destroy({
                where: {
                    name: postName
                }
            })

            res.status(200).send("Successfuly deleted post")
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.status(500).send({
                error: "There was an error deleting this post"
            })
        }
    }
}
```

P.S: Use post ids instead of names, since names arent unique

Answer (score 0):

The way you are exporting your functions is wrong and you have two delete functions.

Export your functions like:

```
  exports.index = async (req,res) => { }
    
  exports.store = async (req,res) => { }
    
  exports.delete = async (req,res) => { }
```

And only use one delete function instead of the two,  there is a name conflict

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't solve my problem. Now I have the PostCotroller with arrow functions, I removed the first delete function, but I have the same error